# My for loop isn't ending

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

my loop is deciding not to end.

Using the code below the output I get is:

```
operatorSize: 1
Check: 0
Check: 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

Code:

```
public int calculateResult(){
    int opCounter = 0;
    int operatorSize = calcOperators.size();
    System.out.println("operatorSize: " + operatorSize);
    for(int i = 0; i < operatorSize; i++){
        for(int s = 1; i<3; i++){
            System.out.println("Check: " + i);
            if (priorityList[i] == s){
                System.out.println("Found one.");
                (Do things)
                opCounter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return calcOperands.get(0);
}
```

If I do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < operatorSize-1; i++)
```

The loop doesn't start at all.

For some reason my loop doesn't want to loop once only.

Comment: This has already been answered, but in the future if you use a debugger and step through the loop looking at what happens with the variables it will allow you to spot these things yourself.

Comment: Wow, I just realised there's a debug mode in Eclipse. I saw the breakpoints but always ran the program with the run button, not F11. This is very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Your `s` for loop is incrementing `i`, not `s`:

```
for(int s = 1; i<3; i++){
```

Try

```
for(int s = 1; s<3; s++){
```

Comment: You always get more upvote from an easy answer that requires no effort, than from a difficult answer that you have to think hard about.  I think it's because people like to upvote answers that they understand easily.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the same thing. I did one answer which was basically "string.length()==0" and got 6 upvotes, other cases where I go into lots of detail, descriptions, etc and I get an accept and one or two upvotes if I'm lucky.